# Rails foreign key other than id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, key

I have an ActiveRecord named Ad, and it has column id and `server_id`. They are both unique. id is given by Rails, but what's meaningful here is `server_id`.

Then I need to create another `ActiveRecord` named Bid which has 1 to 1 relationship with `Ad`. Bid has a key `ad_id` which refers to Ad.`server_id`.

I know that I should specify `Ad has_one Bid` and `Bid belongs_to Ad`, and specify foreign key name through foreign_key: `"ad_id"`. What's troubling me here is I can only find out how to let Bid.`ad_id` refer to Ad.id while I want it refers to Ad.`server_id`.
Can anybody show me how to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User primary key

```
  Bid.rb

  belongs_to :ad, :foreign_key => :ad_id, :primary_key => :server_id


  Ad.rb

  has_one :bid, :foreign_key => :ad_id, :primary_key => :server_id
```

`foregin_key` option is not needed here but adding to make the difference between it and `primary_key` clear.

Comment: Bid.rb
  belongs_to :ad, :foreign_key => :ad_id, :primary_key => :server_id
The primary key server_id here actually points to Ad.server_id, correct?

Comment: ya it would match `server_id` in `Ad` table with `ad_id` in `Bid` table. It works on my console. You can test it out in `rails console` by running `Bid.joins(:ad).to_sql` and see what it is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using '`references`' when generating your model.
i.e.

```
rails generate model Advertisement bid:references
```

Comment: I didn't. I didn't see where to specify the column in Ad that Bid foreign key should refer to.